# Ros2 Dictionary srv/msg type

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, ompl-ros-interface

I would like to be able to return a dictionary as a Response in my interface,
Is it possible to return a python dictionary or should I write code similar to this:

```
uint8 action

---

item1Class dict
-- other msg types below ---
```

where item1Class is a struct

```
This is probably not possible, essentially I want:
```

```
    observation = {
        "lidar": lidar_data,
        "pose": {
            "positionX": X,
            "positionY": Y,
            "orientation": yaw,
        },
    }
```

```
as a srv message where lidar is float32[] and all pose variable are floats.

Whats the best practice using Ros2 to achieve this. Or is this not what srv/msg was intended for?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not a natively supported type. And we actually encourage things to be strongly typed, where a dictionary is not because it can contain approximately arbitrary data. When you receive a ROS datatype it will be a fully defined datatype with it's own structure.

The best practice is to define a `.srv` file to contain these along these lines to cover your description above.

```
uint8 action

---

sensor_msgs/LaserScan lidar_data
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
```

Messages to consider:

- [LaserScan](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/rolling/sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan.msg)
- [Pose](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/rolling/geometry_msgs/msg/Pose.msg)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to return a python dictionary

No, not possible. The type in the .srv file is a **ros message type**, not a python type. You must either 1) define a custom ros message, or 2) return a string that the caller then has to parse (for nested structs like you show, json syntax is popular.)